# python for loop if data duplicate show only one

Tags: python, django, for-loop

hello newbie python learner here. 
i got littlebit confused, i have data like this

```
    attendance = [
        datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 7, 01),
        datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 2, 7, 01),
        datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 3, 7, 01),
        datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 4, 7, 01),
        datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 5, 7, 01),
        datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 5, 7, 21),
        datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 6, 7, 01),
        datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 7, 7, 01),
    ]
```

and i want to show it if day are duplicate or acidentally have twice it will ignore another and only show one that have hour & minutes below another.

in this case i have 2 data that duplicate on

```
     datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 5, 7, 01),
     datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 5, 7, 21)
```

i want its only show

```
    datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 5, 7, 01)
```

since hours/minutes lower than other

i do like this

```
    j = datetime.datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute)

    for i in attendance:
        if i == j:
            do nothing/skip
        else
            print the data

        j = j
```

but its print all the data, not as i want.

Comment: Are the dates sorted, so the duplicates will always be next to each other?

Comment: `i == j` compares both the date and time, not just the date.

Comment: You probably want that last assignment `j=j` to be 'j=i`.

Comment: @Barmar nope, can on 5th .... 100th, its randomly

Comment: @DickyRaambo If it's not sorted, why are you only comparing to the previous element in `j`, instead of checking all previous dates?

Comment: @Barmar that the best idea I have did you have any solution?...  simply any duplicate `day` with same person will be ignored. just show first data submitted.

Comment: Someone posted a very good answer already. If the data isn't already sorted, you can sort it before the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue here is that these two data are not equivalent:

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 5, 7, 01),
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 5, 7, 21)
```

because they differ on the minute value. So == will say that they are different.

```
j = datetime.datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute)

for i in attendance:
    if i.year == j.year and i.month == j.month and i.day == j.day:
        pick the earlier (pseudocode)
    else
        print the data

    j = i
```

Comment: `j = j` should be `j = i`

Comment: thank you, I do short the date first then do for loop. it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Datetime provide a date get function, see [datetime.date()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date/). Just compare the date